# Update only values in a field in a table where criteria is from a linked table

Tags: oracle, sql-update

This is the code I am trying to run, which hopefully makes sense

```
UPDATE OPMAT a 
INNER JOIN ARINVT b
ON a.ARINVT_ID = b.ID
SET a.EXCLUDE_REJECTS_BACKFLUSH = 'Y'
WHERE b.CLASS = 'PK'
```

In English ...Update the field EXCLUDE_REJECTS_BACKFLUSH from table OPMAT where CLASS from table ARINVT  = 'PK' joined on OPMAT.ARINVT_ID = ARINVT.ID

I can do the is MS SQL but cant figure it out in Oracle. Currently getting the error missing SET keyword.

Comment: You might try;

    UPDATE OPMAT
    SET EXCLUDE_REJECTS_BACKFLUSH = 'Y'
    where 0 < (select count(*) from ARINVT where ID = ARINVT_ID and EXCLUDE_REJECTS_BACKFLUSH = 'Y');

Comment: How does this only do records where ARINVT_ID.CLASS = 'PK' ?